# Cant filter by distance (meters) using spatial data in EF Core after update

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, postgis, npgsql, nettopologysuite

I have a table with Geometry column using [EF Core spatial data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/spatial) and [Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL provider](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.NetTopologySuite)

```
class City
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string CityName { get; set; }

    public Point Location { get; set; }
}
```

I used to filter by distance [this way](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/spatial#srid-ignored-during-client-operations)

```
Point myLocation = new Point(longitude, latitude)
{
    SRID = 4326
};
cities = db.Cities.Where(a => a.Location.ProjectTo(2855).Distance(myLocation.ProjectTo(2855)) <= radiusMeters);
```

After update i got following error:

> The LINQ expression 'DbSet()...' could not be translated. Additional information: Translation of method 'App.GeometryExtensions.ProjectTo' failed.

It works without using `ProjectTo()` but counts by degrees. Is there a way to translate this query for work with meters again?

Comment: the problem that EF can't translate methods over IQueryable you can cast the result to list then call where like this
cities = db.Cities.ToList().Where(a => a.Location.ProjectTo(2855).Distance(myLocation.ProjectTo(2855)) <= radiusMeters); but this will effect on performance

Comment: @MohamedHassan it worked before i updated packages. Did they removed this functionallity or it always was client-side?

Comment: really I don't know how it works before but it is fixed from a long time that any method you use in IQuerable where clause should has a similar implementation in SQL engine and based on that EF can translate on DB engine level or you can use AsEnumerable before the filter I experienced this before and this article support what is said if you are able to address kindly share your experience in this particular case.

Comment: I forget to mentions that simple methods like StartWith,... can be translated without runtime exception

Comment: this the link for the article but it seems the URL not in first link <http://tomasp.net/blog/linq-expand.aspx>

Comment: Seeing ProjectTo, it seems like you're using AutoMapper; however, the call to ProjectTo somehow reached EF Core, which it shouldn't (AutoMapper is supposed to do its thing). In other words, try to understand what's going on with AutoMapper, and if that doesn't help, try posting a full query without AutoMapper that reproduces the problem.